# How to use separate PHP error log files for each domain?

Tags: php, iis-7

How can I use separate PHP error log files for each website in IIS server? Currently Apache is providing this feature in htaccess file. Below is the Apache htaccess sample code:

```
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
# enable PHP error logging
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  phperrors.log
# prevent access to PHP error log
<Files PHP_errors.log>
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
 Satisfy All
</Files>
```